# Is there a C# equivalent of Java's BouncyCastleStore?

Tags: java, c#, encryption, bouncycastle, porting

I have a password protected Bouncy Castle key store file created with Bouncy Castle Java API, and I can read key from that store using following Java code:

```
BouncyCastleStore uberStore = new BouncyCastleStore();
char[] uberStorePassword = props.getProperty("keystore.pwd").toCharArray();
FileInputStream finUberStore = new FileInputStream(props.getProperty("keystore.path"));
uberStore.engineLoad(finUberStore, uberStorePassword);
KeyStore.PasswordProtection keystorePassProt = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(uberStorePassword);
SecretKey aesKey = ((KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) uberStore.engineGetEntry(props.getProperty("keystore.alias"), keystorePassProt)).getSecretKey();
```

On the other hand, I have an application in C#, where I have to do some AES-EAX encryption using key stored in the Bouncy Castle key store.

While most of the classes in Bouncy Castle Java cryptography API have their equivalent in Bouncy Castle C# API, I couldn’t find any class in Bouncy Castle C# API that resembles BouncyCastleStore. Therefore I was not able to extract key from the Bouncy Castle key store file via C#.
Is it possible to read this key store using c#?

**Edit**: I’ve rephrased my inital question because it was somehow misleading (thanks to @cryptic_star). My goal is not to make exact translation of sampled Java code, but to find whatever possible way to extract key from Bouncy Castle key store using C#.

Comment: It would be helpful to more explicitly state what problem you're having translating between Java and C#.

Comment: I don't see anything either. It looks like you may have to write your own code from scratch, or extract the keys from a Java program and write them to a C# keystore format. It looks like BouncyCastle C# supports a PKCS12Store, though I'm not sure if that supports secret keys.

Comment: C# or .NET in general uses Windows built in support for certificate stores and so forth, so you will have to relevant API to replace that.

Comment: @JamesKPolk That was my backup plan - using Java code to extract key, and store it afterwards in Windows certificate store, as Lex Li suggested. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

BouncyCastle on C# can only read PKCS12 files or PEM (Base64 coded) files.
Currently I don't see a way to read jks.